# How to making expandable an appbar in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-appbar

I am trying to create an AppBar in Flutter that expands downwards when I click on the arrow icon (similar to the effect shown in this image).

[image: todo]

The current AppBar implementation I have is shown below:

```
AppBar homeAppbar(HomeProvider homeprovider) {
    return AppBar(
      leading: Builder(builder: (context) {
        return IconButton(
          icon: ImageUtils.imageUtilsInstance
              .showSVGIcons(menuIcon, height: 30.h),
          onPressed: () {
            Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
          },
        );
      }),
      title: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text(homeprovider.currentLocation.city!,
              style: textSemiBold(size: 18, color: colortextBlack)),
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                homeprovider.getCurrentCity();
              },
              icon: homeprovider.gettingCurrentcity
                  ? SizedBox(
                      height: 20.h,
                      width: 20.h,
                      child: const CircularProgressIndicator(
                        strokeWidth: 1,
                      ))
                  : const Icon(
                      Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_rounded,
                      color: colorGrey74797D,
                    ))
        ],
      ),
      actions: [
        AuthService().getUserUID != null
            ? homeprovider.gettingProfile
                ? SizedBox(
                    height: 20.h,
                    width: 20.h,
                    child: const CircularProgressIndicator(strokeWidth: 1))
                : IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      homeprovider.profilePressed();
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.person,
                      color: colortextBlack,
                    ))
            : IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  changeScreenReplacement(routeName: signInRoute);
                },
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.person,
                  color: colortextBlack,
                ),
              ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.w),
        )
      ],
    );
}
```

While I have managed to integrate the arrow icon, I am not sure how to make the AppBar expand when it's clicked. Any guidance or resources on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

**EDIT**

The best result I have, following answers is that:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter AppBar Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  // Ajout de la variable isOpen
  bool isOpen = false;

  // Simulons quelques variables pour cette démonstration.
  final String city = 'Paris';
  final Color colortextBlack = Colors.black;
  final bool isLoadingCity = false;
  final bool isLoadingProfile = false;
  final bool isUserLoggedIn = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: Builder(
          builder: (context) {
            return IconButton(
              icon:
                  Icon(Icons.menu), // Remplacé par un simple icône pour la démo
              onPressed: () {
                Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
              },
            );
          },
        ),
        title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const Text("App title"),
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(isOpen
                    ? Icons.keyboard_arrow_up
                    : Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    isOpen = !isOpen;
                  });
                })
          ],
        ),
        bottom: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(isOpen ? 120 : 0),
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(24.0),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(24.0),
            ),
            child: isOpen
                ? Container(
                    height: 120,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: "Entrez quelque chose ici...",
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                        TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: "Entrez encore...",
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  )
                : Container(),
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          isUserLoggedIn
              ? isLoadingProfile
                  ? SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                      width: 20,
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(strokeWidth: 1))
                  : IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        // Logique pour le profil
                      },
                      icon: Icon(Icons.person, color: colortextBlack),
                    )
              : IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    // Redirige vers la page de connexion
                  },
                  icon: Icon(Icons.person, color: colortextBlack),
                ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(child: Text('Corps de la page')),
    );
  }
}
```

Which had for a result this:

[image]

**SOLUTION**

I'm back with the final solution that i found with your help guys and other here's the code bellow :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Custom AppBar',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;
  late Animation<double> _animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250));
    _animation = CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.easeInOut);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 50,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text('Item $index'),
                );
              },
            ),
            AnimatedBuilder(
              animation: _controller,
              builder: (context, child) {
                return Stack(
                  children: [
                    if (_controller.value > 0)
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          if (_controller.isCompleted) {
                            _controller.reverse();
                          }
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          color:
                              Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3 * _controller.value),
                          width: double
                              .infinity, // S'assurer qu'il s'étend sur toute la largeur
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context)
                              .size
                              .height, // S'assurer qu'il s'étend sur toute la hauteur
                        ),
                      ),
                    child!,
                  ],
                );
              },
              child: CustomAppBar(
                animation: _animation,
                onArrowTap: () {
                  if (_controller.isCompleted) {
                    _controller.reverse();
                  } else {
                    _controller.forward();
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class CustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final Animation<double> animation;
  final VoidCallback onArrowTap;

  CustomAppBar({required this.animation, required this.onArrowTap});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(24),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(24),
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.menu, color: Colors.black),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: onArrowTap,
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Text("Menu"),
                        SizedBox(width: 8),
                        RotationTransition(
                          turns: animation,
                          child:
                              Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down, color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.black),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(24),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(24),
              ),
              child: SizeTransition(
                sizeFactor: animation,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  height: 100.0,
                  child: Center(child: Text("Contenu étendu")),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I decided to create a widget as an appBar.

Comment: You can try slivers like [SliverAppBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html)  .

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i tried something with SliverAppBar but without success, have you got any example to reach the goal i target ?

Answer (score 2):

`AppBar` has a property `bottom`. Try this example. Customize it yourself.

```
  title: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        const Text("App title"),
        IconButton(
            icon: Icon(isOpen
                ? Icons.keyboard_arrow_up
                : Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                isOpen = !isOpen;
              });
            })
      ],
    ),
    bottom: PreferredSize(
      preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(isOpen ? 100 : 0),
      child: isOpen
          ? Container(color: Colors.black, height: 100)
          : Container(),
    ),
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i tried to customize your code, but it's seems that is not possible to make a border radius to the appbar. Have you any solution ?

Comment: Maybe you've already solved the radius problem. and I saw you've tried using the bottom property of the AppBar widget. Don't forget to select this answer as useful if it helped you.

Comment: It works but not perfectly as i want, if you have any solution i'm in !

Answer (score 0):

You can override the shape on AppBar on your current snippet.

```dart
appBar: AppBar(
  shape: isOpen
      ? RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
            bottom: Radius.circular(24),
          ),
        )
      : null,
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is indeed almost that, on the other hand, I see a small blue border appearing on the left and right sides, how can I make it disappear?

Comment: you can change the `backgroundColor: ` of appBar as well, or just play around with radius(26).

Comment: Ok i got that, by the way, do you know how can i add the "overlay" when the appbar is open ?
I tried it, but it seems that the radius desapear.

Comment: You can use Overlay widget for that ig